# How to turn down the brightness on my Dell mini laptop?

Tags: dell, brightness

The keys that show the brightness symbols are <kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd>, but when I hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press these, it only shows <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd>. Help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get brightness control working, follow this steps:

1. Install acpi, to do so, open a terminal (CTLR + ALT + T) and type `sudo apt-get install acpi`.
2. Edit the grub configuration, to do so, type this: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
3. Locate the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"` and replace it with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`.
4. Update the GRUB, in order to do that, type: `sudo update-grub2`.
5. Finally, reboot and your brightness control should work by now.

By the way, you should use the <kbd>FN</kbd> key, not the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. <kbd>Shift</kbd> is used to type alternative characters, while <kbd>FN</kbd> is used to control the hardware.

Hope this helps.